# How to handle $("#C+++p") in jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML like this:

```
<div class='item'>
    <h1 id="C++">C++</h1>
    <p>some thing</p>
</div>
```

I want to use jQuery selector to select the p tag, I write:

```
$("#C+++p")
```

But It failed. Than I read the document about jQuery selector and made some change:

```
$("#C//+//+//+p")
```

It still not worked. What's the problem of my code? Thank you!

Comment: You use backslashes, not forward slashes, to escape special characters in jQuery selectors.

Comment: [This ID is valid in HTML5, but not in HTML4](http://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/560648) and I'd avoid using the `+` character in general. The problem you're facing is just one reason why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example you used the wrong slashes. To escape characters in a jQuery selector string you need to use two backslashes `\\`.

```
$('#C\\+\\+')
```

After escaping you can add the rest of the selector

```js
alert($('#C\\+\\+ + p').text())
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='item'>
    <h1 id="C++">C++</h1>
    <p>some thing</p>
</div>
```

Note: You only need to escape the +'s that are part of the ID or class.